# PyQt5 Designer does not load custom widgets with Ananconda 3

Tags: python, plugins, widget, anaconda, pyqt5

I am attempting to write a custom widget with Python 3.7 to be used in Qt Designer 5.9.6.  I had to manually download and copy `libpyqt5.so` into the `anaconda3/plugins/designer` directory as it is not included in the anaconda3 `pyqt5` package.

The `libpyqt5` plugin is now successfully loaded into Qt Designer but Designer is not picking up the widgets from the working directory with `PYQTDESIGNERPATH=. designer &`

Comment: I also get this issue in Windows. pyqt5.dll gets loaded successfully into Qt Designer, but then the custom widgets don't get imported. I am talking with someone from riverbank computing at the moment; they have just fixed a windows bug for me (which stopped stopped the pyqt5.dll file from loading properly before.) - I'll bring this up with them now.

Comment: @LostCrotchet, I am eager to hear what Riverbank Computing say.  Please keep me updated.  Thanks.